# Trouble with Using Custom Theorems with Roboto Font

Tags: fonts, theorems

I am having trouble with making a custom Theorem environment using Roboto font. Basically, I want the theorem header to use `\fontseries{medium}` instead of `\bfseries`. When working with this, I have made two observations:

1. Only the number of the theorem takes on this new font.
2. If I change the theorem body style to `\fontseries{medium}`, only text that is emphasized using `\emph{}` takes on the new font.

Here is a MWE and the resulting output:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault, light]{roboto}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsthm, bm}
\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
    {\topsep}
    {\topsep}
    {\fontseries{medium}} % only changes emphasized text
    {}
    {\fontseries{medium}} % only changes theorem number
    {}
    {0.5em}
    {}
    \theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \begin{theorem}
        The \emph{expected value} of a continuous random variable \(X\) with support \(\Omega\) is given by 
        \begin{align*}
            \mathbb{E}(X) \coloneqq \int_{\Omega} \mathrm{d} F(x) = \int_{\Omega} f(x) \;\mathrm{d} x,
        \end{align*}
        where \(f\) and \(F\) denote the pdf and cdf, respectively. 
    \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `light` option of the `roboto` package, when you use Type 1 fonts, redefines the medium weight. What you want here is the `\robotomedium` command:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault, light]{roboto}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsthm, bm}
\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
    {\topsep}
    {\topsep}
    {\robotomedium} % changed
    {}
    {\robotomedium} % changed
    {}
    {0.5em}
    {}
    \theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \begin{theorem}
        The \emph{expected value} of a continuous random variable \(X\) with support \(\Omega\) is given by 
        \begin{align*}
            \mathbb{E}(X) \coloneqq \int_{\Omega} \mathrm{d} F(x) = \int_{\Omega} f(x) \;\mathrm{d} x,
        \end{align*}
        where \(f\) and \(F\) denote the pdf and cdf, respectively. 
    \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

This also works in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, which make `roboto` use the OTF fonts.